# Stored procedure intermittently hangs due to MemoryGrant delay

Tags: sql-server

Running `SQL Server 2014`. I have a stored procedure that performs multiple joins on several tables. It usually runs in 5 milliseconds, but once in a while it takes up to 30 seconds. I can repeat this on a **local, single-user, standalone database** (`Express Edition`) by simply running the query in `SQL Management Studio` - like 50 times.

The database is almost empty. There are some 100-1000 rows at most, and all columns are indexed. How can a query run in **3 ms** fifty times in a row and then suddenly take **30 seconds** - with NO other active connections?

### UPDATE

I can confirm that the delay is caused by a `MemoryGrant` delay. The execution plan shows this warning:

> The query had to wait 11 seconds for MemoryGrant during execution

**How can I prevent this from happening?** I don't understand why there would be a memory problem when previous runs of this query could be freed instantly.

Comment: can you grab an execution plan for both a "good" run of the SP and a "bad" run of the SP?  That might shed some insight

Comment: Are you sure it's SQL server alone?  Check to see what the wait statistics look like as well as what's happening in performance monitor during your queries execution.  If you're running the same query over and over, the data you care about is likely in memory.  So, either you have resource contention or the machine you are on has other processes competing for memory or CPU.

Comment: @Kritner, how do I grab the execution plan for a previous run of the SP? Or are you suggesting that I hit `Ctrl+L` until it hangs?